# Azure table storage Retention Policy

Tags: azure, azure-table-storage, retention

Working with Azure storage, I can of course set the retention policy for blobs. 
But I would like to learn if there's possibility to set retention policy over Azure table storage. and the only article I found on Microsoft documentation was this one. : [Set Table Service Properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/set-table-service-properties)

According to this article by calling the PUT API for setting table service, we can enable or disable the retention policies for storage table service. 
But why I can't find any means to set this property on Azure portal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But I would like to learn if there's possibility to set retention
>   policy over Azure table storage.

It is not possible to set the retention policy for entities in Azure Table Storage. Retention policy is only available for Blobs in blob storage.

Set table service properties operation sets the [`storage analytics`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-analytics) settings for table service (along with CORS settings). The retention policy you see there is for the retention of storage analytics logs and metrics data collected by storage analytics for table service.

Comment: Thanks now I get it :)

Comment: @Afflatus Can we really set deny effect on policy to restrict storage account deployment to ensure soft delete on blob storage? Do we have a policy defined on this I tried with this.... "field": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/blobServices/deleteRetentionPolicy.enabled",
 "equals": false        but didn't apply...